# Eigenvalues of Laplace operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

Assume that $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold.

Is there any relation between the sequence of eigenvalues of Laplace operator acting on the space of smooth functions and the sequence of eigenvalues of Laplace operator acting on the space of smooth $k$-forms for $k\neq 0$?

Comment: It is not directly related to your question, BUT read $\text{Analytic torsion}$, $\text{Ray–Singer torsion}$, or if you want to have more fantasy ;) BCOV Invariants read this interesting paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601411 I read it several months ago . Note that BCOV invariant play an important role in degeneration of KE metrics

Comment: See http://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/nat_Fak_I/Bunke/sixtorsion.pdf and p.16 of my master thesis in Aix-Marseille in south of France https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1211/1211.4171.pdf

Comment: See Minakshisundaram formula in p.12 http://www.math.mcgill.ca/toth/spectral%20geometry.pdf we have same type formula when you work on $p$-forms

Comment: Let me give more philosophical picture about my first comment: Bershadsky–Cecotti-Ooguri-Vafa invariant is a Ray–Singer torsion(Analytic torsion)  used in mirror symmetry and play an important role in the degeneration of Calabi-Yau varieties. The good thing is that we can extend BCOV invariant for varieties of general type which give naïve connection to  Ginzburg–Landau theory and study of Analytic torsion. So the same nature of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601411 can be extended when fibers admit Kahler-Einstein metrics of negative Ricci curvature and geometry of Quillen metrics

Comment: @HassanJolany  Many thanks for your very  interesting information and links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have heard, and are trying to remember the statement of, the following fact about the *Hodge Laplacian* $d^*d+dd^*$ on forms.

Slogan: eigenforms come in pairs.

Sketch proof:  If $(d^*d+dd^*)\eta=-\lambda\eta$, then $(d^*d+dd^*)(d\eta)=dd^*d\eta=d(d^*d+dd^*)\eta=-\lambda d\eta$.

Statement:  Recall the Hodge decomposition $\Gamma(M,\Lambda^kM)=A_k\oplus B_k\oplus H_k=\operatorname{im}(d^*_{k+1})\oplus\operatorname{im}(d_{k-1})\oplus (\operatorname{ker}(d_k^*)\cap\operatorname{ker}(d_k))$, such that for all $k$, $d_k:A_k\to B_{k+1}$ is an isomorphism.  Then for each $\lambda$, $d_k$ sends the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $A_k$ to the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $B_{k+1}$.

Special case:  Each nonzero eigenvalue of the Laplace operator on functions is also an eigenvalue of the Laplace operator on 1-forms.

Also, if you take any [sensible choice whatsoever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operators_in_differential_geometry) of Laplacian on $\Gamma(M,\Lambda^kM)$, then the asymptotic distribution (à la Weyl) of the eigenvalues will be the same as the asymptotic distribution of the eigenvalues of the Laplacian on scalars (up to multiplication by the rank of $\Lambda^kM$).  See, eg, Theorem 2.41 of Berline-Getzler-Vergne.

Comment: Weyl is German, so why "à la Weyl"?!!!

Comment: @HassanJolany English borrowed many foreign expressions. See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_la#English

Comment: @ACL , à la, borrowed also In my grand mothers language means "handsome " and my fathers language means "this side" . I know that in Turkish language means God , so I believe you!

Comment: @HassanJolany Good point! The expression exists in French, meaning “in the style of” and the similar one — alla — exists in Italian. One more letter closer to God.

Comment: @ACL Many thanks for your very interesting information and explanation

Comment: @macbeth Thank you very much for your answer and your attention to my question.